# How to add diff inline decorators to Monaco similar to VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I would like to highlight the changes that the user did inside the editor similar to the way VSCode GIT extension highlights the changes inline the editor. I'm aware that there is DiffEditor in Monaco but I don't need to compare the versions side by side, I just want to give the visual feedback to the user similar to this example:

[image]

Does Monaco support this feature? If not, can I use Monaco's DiffEditor to find out the changes and add inline decorators to the editor?